# MaxReceivedMessageSize (65536) exceeded in .Net Core API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, binding

We have netcoreapp2.2 API, with the standard structure, this is program.cs, startup,cs and some Controllers.

The issue we are having, is that sometimes, it throws an error:

```
Maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded
```

We have this API pulished in IIS, so we just build the API with `dotnet publish - c Release`

And this generates the `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish` folder, that we then copy to the IIS App

Is there any code we can put into Startup.cs, so that generated web.config has the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` we manually decide, in stead of the default 65536

Our Startup.cs is very standard, like the one in this page https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1):

If you're hosting your app on IIS, you need to configure this on the IIS level, not within ASP.NET Core code. The dotnet publish process does not customize IIS `web.config` based on things in the ASP.NET Core code (like `Startup.cs`).

You can however include a `web.config` with the following content in the base directory of your project. The publish process that transforms the `web.config` file will start from an existing `web.config` in your project if it is present.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The relevant docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2#webconfig-file-location):

> If a web.config file isn't present in the project, the file is created with the correct processPath and arguments to configure the ASP.NET Core Module and moved to published output.
>
> If a web.config file is present in the project, the file is transformed with the correct processPath and arguments to configure the ASP.NET Core Module and moved to published output. The transformation doesn't modify IIS configuration settings in the file.

Comment: Will the maxAllowedContentLength overide the maxReceiveMessageSize property ? or I need to create a binding?

Comment: @JackCasas you have today the answer of this question you just made 2 years ago? I'm wondering the same.

Comment: @SamyCode Sure, just posted my answer. A bit late, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Web services supported the message of length 65536, by default. If you want to change the web services message length, change in client service.

try to add the maxReceiveMessageSize property to the binding tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="EntitySoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
<security mode="Transport" />
</binding>             
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint address="https://mywebsite.com/WebServices/DataService.asmx"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EntitySoap"
contract="MyNamespace.EntitySoap" name="EntitySoap" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

We finally solved it with one of these:

In our code, when creating the http client:

```
public PortClient setClient(){
        BasicHttpBinding WSBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        WSBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2000000;
        WSBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        WSBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(configuration.GetConnectionString("Service"));
        
        
        Lib_PortClient client = new Lib_PortClient(navWSBinding,endpoint);   
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "P@ssss");  //System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        return client;
    }
```

web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="200000000" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```